# Specific UI preferences & user behaviours in Singapore

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, localization

**Background** 
I am currently working on an ecommerce site for Singapore, in particular their product detail page. A design was already provided but I worked on a small task where I have changed the width of reading columns to keep to best practice for reading. Attached is the wireframe where the product information has been reduced in width and central align where originally it was the full width of the container.

I have now been told that customers are complaining of the white space thats now there (still waiting on the evidence).

**My question**
This had me thinking about moving away from global best practices and try to find any specific UI preferences & user behaviours for Singapore customers. Is there anything out there that you can recommend as useful to my research?

So far I have yet to find anything beyond buying & device using statistics. A quick view at the [most popular ecommerce sites](https://aseanup.com/top-e-commerce-sites-singapore/) shows examples of stronger colours and more information density. But I was wondering if there is any other sources out there that can give me greater insight.

[image]

Comment: What type of page is it? Is that a journal, product display, search results, home page? Could you please share a mockup of the page? Keeping text paragraph-widths within easy reading limits does not mean that the rest of the white space cannot be occupied by images or charts or a video.

Comment: thanks @Ren, I have updated the question to give greater detail. Visually I am thinking of two options: 1) consider card UI for the descriptions to enhance focus on the text. 2) look at two column card design. While I will mock those up for the client, I always thought it would be beneficial to build up my localisation knowledge in UX, hence the original question.

Comment: Just to confirm, this situation has been brought about by an objection to white-space?

Comment: Yes that is correct @DarrylGodden